# Where can I report US immigration fraud?

Tags: usa

A colleague of mine has confessed to me that he applied for asylum in the US with a fake story about persecution in his home country. His application is in the last stages of processing and I'm afraid that he would be granted asylum despite not deserving it in the slightest.

How can I report this fact to the authorities? ICE has a tip off line about illegal aliens, but my colleague currently has legal status so he's not technically illegal. Is there a specific tip off line for asylum fraud?

Comment: I should say that the chances of this being prosecuted under the current president are very low. I reported someone that used *my* name as a sponsor for asylum (I only found out because they asked for my personal information and I asked why); and I only got a single phone call from the government. I missed the call, and tried calling back within 1 minute, and got a message to wait for them to call me again; they never did. At one point, the asylee told me they got questioned about why the "sponsor e-mail address" is actually theirs; so they re-assured the agent, and got their status approved.